# Lookup value from DataTable C#

Tags: c#

Just trying to lookup a value from a DataTable but I'm getting an error.

I want to find the value in column JobID based on the user entered value of Ref.

Here's my code:

```
string jobid = (from DataRow dr in Variables.jobstable.Rows
where (string)dr["Ref"] == ctjobreference.Text
select (string)dr["JobID"]).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here's the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'

I tried changing the types in my code to int but that didn't seem to help - what am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: try something like (long)dr["JobID"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't cast:

```
(string)dr["JobID"]
```

Use `.ToString()`:

```
dr["JobID"].ToString()
```

Casting doesn't use the object's conversion methods, it tells the runtime itself that the type should be something else.  And those types are not interchangeable.